# Search for words with specific starts and endings

Tags: javascript, regex

I asked a pretty detailed question earlier but it got flagged as a duplicate even though it wasn't.

So I will try and explain what I am trying to do as simply as I can. I want to search a text string for words that begin with specific letters such as "mak", "mind" and "mass" (which are in an array) and end with either nothing extra or "e" or "er". That would be in this instance "mak", "make", "maker", "mind", "minde", "minder", "mass", "masse", "masser".

The code I am using only finds the first match for each word in the array, for instance "mak", "mind" and "mass" in the example.

```
derPro = ['mak','mind', 'mass', ;
for(i = 0; i < derPro.length; i++){
searchTerm = new RegExp(
                    "\\b" + derPro[i] + "\\b|" +
                    "\\b" + derPro[i] + "e\\b|" +
                    "\\b" + derPro[i] + "er\\b,'gi'");
word = testText.match(searchTerm, "gi");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var derPro = ['mak','mind', 'mass'];

var searchTerm = new RegExp('\\b((?:' + derPro.join('|') + ')(?:er?)?)\\b', "gi");
//=> /\b((?:mak|mind|mass)(?:er?)?)\b/gi

// now match the regex in a while loop
var matches=[]
while (m = searchTerm.exec('mass maker minde')) matches.push(m[1]);

console.log(matches);

//=> ["mass", "maker", "minde"]
```

Comment: please can you tell me what is wrong in my regex pattern.

Comment: Sorry @Braj, doesn't look like anything wrong with your regex either. Not sure why it got downboted.

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
/(\b(mak|mind|mass)(e|er)?\b)/gi
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/cJ7eE6/2)

Answer (score 0):

This works, i know you asked for a regex, but I thought this would be useful.

```
var keys = [
  'mak',
  'mind',
  'mass'
];

var test_words = [
  'mak',
  'make',
  'maker',
  'mind',
  'mass'
];

var matches = [];

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var key = keys[i];

  for(var ii = 0; ii < test_words.length; ii++) {
    var test_word = test_words[ii];

    if(test_word.substr(0, key.length) == key) {

      if( test_word.substr(-1) == 'e' || test_word.substr(-2) == 'er') {
        matches.push(test_word);

      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(matches);
// [make, maker, minde]
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJ6rn/)