# Regex to extract a string

Tags: regex

I have a string as

```
Celcom10 | 105ABCD | Celcom
```

This is my regex `(\s\w+)` however this also capture the white space.

How do I write a regex to obtain the middle values `105ABCD` **excluding** the pipe and whitespace ?

I only need a `regex pattern` since this will be inserted within a diagram which will be executed in an automated test.

Comment: And what language are you using?

Comment: @abiieez Then split by `\s*[|]\s*`, you'll get an array

Comment: I cant use split function because this regex will be put within an ARIS diagram

Comment: @abiieez If that's the case then use `[^\s|]+`. But really, please try to clarify your question from the start by giving maximal information. Getting to the "real" question after 7 edits is a __pain__. Also if you're using some custom program, then why in the world are you asking us on how to get a specific group. Try to search on your own since it's not pure javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this also

```
[^ |]+
```

Comment: How can I modify that to get the first, second or third only ?

Comment: I need only the middle value `105ABCD`

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy and straightforward if you split the string by: `\s*[|]\s*`

**Explanation:**

1. `\s*` match optional whitespaces
2. `[|]` match a literal pipe, `|` means **or** in regex but if you put it in a character class `[]` it loses it's meaning
3. `\s*` match optional whitespaces

**Sample code:**

```
input = 'somenickname | 1231231 | brand';
output = input.split(/\s*[|]\s*/);

// Printing
for(i = 0, l = output.length;i < l;i++){
    document.write('index: ' + i + ' & value: ' + output[i] + '<br>');
}
```

**Output:**

```
index: 0 & value: somenickname
index: 1 & value: 1231231
index: 2 & value: brand
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need a regex (or maybe 3) to extract all the three words / number (excluding the whitespace and pipe)

Get the matched group from index 1. Here parenthesis `(...)` is used to capture the groups.

```
(\w+)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/5)

```
\w       match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Have a look at the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725161/search-for-words-with-specific-starts-and-endings?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: What if these words has any special character?

Comment: Using a capturing group is redundant here.

Comment: that works thanks. Can I choose to capture the 2nd or 3rd occurrence only ?

Comment: Is the group index used to extract the which text matches ? I still cant figure it out

Comment: I need a regex, not split function.